# Transform MySQL 'update' statements to 'insert' statements

Tags: mysql, insert

I have an 11MB dump containing UPDATE statements, formatted like this:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `id` = 1,`field`='etc' WHERE `table`.`id` = 1;
```

However, I need to insert these values into a new database, using statements like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `field`) VALUES ('etc', 1);
```

Has anyone written a tool or service to convert `UPDATE` statements to `INSERT` statements? (At first glance, it seems to be just beyond the reach of regex)

Comment: If you wrote a tool for it, it wouldve been done by now ;-)

Comment: I'm working overtime on it as we speak. Commas and escaped quotes are proving more annoying than I hoped.

Comment: I bet http://code.google.com/p/python-sqlparse would have helped... but too late now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy approach. If you have the ids, insert no matter what for those id's and after that run the updates.

Comment: Awesome thinking, man. It's always the simplest thing that works the best.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is beyond the reach of a regex. Foreach line in the dump, use the following :

```
Pattern :       ^.*`id` = (\d+).*`field`='(.*)'[^']*WHERE.*$
Replacement :   INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `field`) VALUES ('$2', $1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the list of fields is not this simple, although this could be worked around. But what about, for example, `field`='\'a\'=\'x\',\'y\''?

Comment: @zildjohn01 Ok i have updated the regex. I assumed you have only two fields.

Answer (score 0):

This simple regex search and replace in notepad++ will convert any update into an insert:

```
Search for: UPDATE (.*) SET (.*) WHERE .*$
Replace with: INSERT INTO \1 SET \2;
```

This assumes that what followed the "where" was originally a unique key. It changes it so that key will auto-increment when you insert.